# How can I create an environment variable that contains the IP address of an adapter that is set via DHCP?

Tags: 18.04, server, environment-variables, docker

I am using docker and my scripts reference an environment variable that I'm manually setting in user's **foo** account /etc/environment like:

```
SERVER_IP=172.16.16.29
```

I'm using in my docker-compose file (which I'm running under as **foo**)

```
environment:
  - ServerIP=${SERVER_IP}
```

I would like to be able to have a variable **DHCP_IP** that will be populated when adapter **enp0s3** has it's IP address set so that I can use **DHCP_IP**  in place of **SERVER_IP** in the docker-compose above.

I'm not concerned about the IP address changing often as I'm using MAC address filtering in my router to assign the same IP.  But I don't want to have to set the IP address manually in a file like I'm doing now.

So how can I put the value of the ip address of **enp0s3** into a variable called **DHCP_IP**, and how can I reference that at the command line or in a file?

Or if you know of an alternative, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: `DHCP_IP="$(ip addr show enp0s3 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)"`

Comment: I can get the IP already.  How do I put it to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

The adapter in question is: `enp0s3`, so change that accordingly

```
IP="$(ip addr show enp0s3  | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }' | cut -d/ -f1)"
export SERVER_IP=${IP}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following approach:

Suppose that your ethernet name is `ens160`:

```bsh
IP=http://"$(ifconfig ens160 | awk '/inet /{print $2}' | cut -f2 -d':')"
```

Or:

```bsh
IP=http://"$(hostname -I | cut -f1 -d' ')"
```

Test:

```bsh
echo $IP

http://192.168.100.146
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple commands that should work:

```
IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')

IP=$(ip addr show | grep 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1 | head -n 3 | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).